# Mercurial files Extraction

Tags: mercurial-extension

I was trying to extract just the modified files between two revisions along with its folder location structure.

I have loaded your extension pack.py and ran the command exportfiles but could not crack it. The loaded extension appears inactive but the selected. The error remains as "unknown command exportfiles". Struggling with this for a week. Do I need to do anything more. Am I doing it wrong. Please help me

Comment: Can you provide more specific details?  It's not very clear exactly what you're attempting to do

Comment: i want to extract the modified files between two revisions. For that I have came across a command "exportfiles" and the extension "pack.py" for it. So loaded the pack.py and added the extension in mercurial.ini. we can see the extension in the settings window but its not active(unable).

Comment: i tried with command "hg exportfiles -r r1:r2 /tmp/export" without the above mentioned extension, this gave me all the files. But i just wanted the modified files between those two revisions.

Comment: Hi Taegost, Good Day today!! Finally cracked it. Found the proper script for exportfiles extension, saved the script as .py file and loaded the extensions. Its up and running(the command). Thanks for the participation and time. As I was searching for the past week, I can say that this is the place to find the accurate solution for this issue. Thanks to that genius Albert Brand.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day today!! Found the proper script for exportfiles extension, saved the script as .py file and loaded the extensions. Its up and running(the command). As I was searching for the past week, I can say that this is the place to find the accurate solution. Thanks to the genius Albert Brand.

exportfiles.py------
https://bitbucket.org/albert_brand/hgexportfiles/src/eec1a0848787bdc9ca561df0169dc76b16895f82/exportfiles.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default